.NET 8 "Some services are not able to be constructed" Error
Error:

System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces.ICarRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CarRepository': Implementation type 'CarRepository' can't be converted to service type 'BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces.ICarRepository') (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BookACar.Application.Features.CQRS.Handlers.CarHandlres.GetCarWithBrandQueryHandler Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BookACar.Application.Features.CQRS.Handlers.CarHandlres.GetCarWithBrandQueryHandler': Implementation type 'CarRepository' can't be converted to service type 'BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces.ICarRepository')
Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Projects\CarBook\Presentation\BookACar.WebApi\Program.cs:line 51
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces.ICarRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CarRepository': Implementation type 'CarRepository' can't be converted to service type 'BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces.ICarRepository'
Inner Exception 2:
ArgumentException: Implementation type 'CarRepository' can't be converted to service type 'BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces.ICarRepository'

ICarRepository interface:
namespace BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces
{
    public interface ICarRepository
    {
        List<Car> GetCarsListWithBrand();
    }
}

CarRepository class:
namespace BookACar.Persistence.Repositories.CarRepositories
{
    public class CarRepository : ICarRepository
    {
        private readonly CarBookContext _context;

        public CarRepository(CarBookContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<Car> GetCarsListWithBrand()
        {
            var values = _context.Cars.Include(x => x.Brand).ToList();
            return values;
        }
    }
}

program.cs:
using BookACar.Application.Features.CQRS.Handlers.AboutHandlers;
using BookACar.Application.Features.CQRS.Handlers.BannerHandlres;
using BookACar.Application.Features.CQRS.Handlers.BrandHandlers;
using BookACar.Application.Features.CQRS.Handlers.CarHandlres;
using BookACar.Application.Interfaces;
using BookACar.Application.Interfaces.CarInterfaces;
using BookACar.Persistence.Repositories;
using BookACar.Persistence.Repositories.CarRepositories;
using CarBook.Persistence.CarBookContext;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddScoped<CarBookContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(ICarRepository), typeof(CarRepository));

builder.Services.AddScoped<GetCarQueryHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<GetCarByIdQueryHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CreateCarCommandHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UpdateCarCommandHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RemoveCarCommandHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<GetCarWithBrandQueryHandler>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I tried all ways but I can't fix the problem. Why I am getting this error and how I can fix it?

The error is not reproducible from the code examples you posted. The most likely cause is that there is a second class in your solution called CarRepository, which doesn't implement ICarRepository. @decius's answer helps in that respect, because you'll likely get a compile error instead of a runtime error stating that the used CarRepository doesn't implement ICarRepository.

Try this, because the advantage is that the compiler can then enforce that the implementation (CarRepository) provides the service (ICarRepository) - which rules out confusion over a different service/implementation that has the same name but is fundamentally different:
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();

Check also if you have a second CarRepository class which is not inherited from ICarRepository.

The typeof approach should still work with AddScoped for non-generic types; the huge advantage of AddScoped<ICarRepository, CarRepository>, however, is that the compiler can then enforce that the implementation (CarRepository) provides the service (ICarRepository) - which rules out confusion over a different service/implementation that has the same name but is fundamentally different

You´re right. I will add that to my answer. thx.

Changing Scope of Car repository from generic class to
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(ICarRepository), typeof(CarRepository));

to
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();

should work

That isn't valid syntax; I suspect you mean the code in decius's answer, but: that answer is 8 hours earlier than this, so...
